# Content-Disposition: attachment / Content-Type not downloading file in iOS

Tags: php, icalendar, concrete5

```
header('Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=invite.ics');
```

The `invite.ics` file is downloading in all browsers expect Safari.
In Safari browser it is getting opened as a file, not downloaded as `invite.ics`.

Have any idea?

Comment: Did you try to change the content type to application/octet-stream ?

Comment: yes , no change

Comment: Using the Developer tools (on desktop), inspect the response headers of your request: maybe some other PHP code overrides the ones you are setting.